# Split a string into double pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

i am trying to convert a string (example: "hey there mister") into a double pointer that's pointing to every word in the sentence. 
so: split_string->|pointer1|pointer2|pointer3| where pointer1->"hey", pointer2->"there" and pointer3->"mister".

```
char **split(char *s) {
    char **nystreng = malloc(strlen(s));
    char str[strlen(s)];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++){
        str[i] = s[i];
    }

    char *temp;
    temp = strtok(str, " ");

    int teller = 0;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        nystreng[teller] = temp;
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    nystreng[teller++] = NULL;

    //free(nystreng);

    return nystreng;
}
```

My question is, why isnt this working?

Comment: At which point in your program is it failing to do what you think it's doing?

Comment: Please tell us what "isn't working" means in this context. What output are you getting?

Comment: Straight off the bat, this looks highly suspicious: `char **nystreng = malloc(strlen(s));`.  It's unclear why the required space would be equal to the length of `s` and independent of the size of a `char *`.

Comment: strlen(s) returns a length that doesn't include the terminating nul char. This means that your "for" loop isn't copying the terminator, so strtok will go off the end of the buffer, at which point bad things will generally happen.

Comment: Also, why are you copying strings manually with for loops? Use an API like `strcpy` or `strncpy`.

Comment: A pointer is not an array is not a pointer!

Comment: From the code posted I got a segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems.  Among them:

- `char **nystreng = malloc(strlen(s));` is just wrong.  The amount of space you need is the size of a `char *` times the number pieces into which the string will be split plus one (for the NULL pointer terminator).
- You fill `*nystreng` with pointers obtained from `strtok()` operating on *local* array `str`.  Those pointers are valid only for the lifetime of `str`, which ends when the function returns.
- You do not allocate space for a string terminator in `str`, and you do not write one, yet you pass it to `strtok()` as if it were a terminated string.
- You do not increment `teller` inside your tokenization loop, so each token pointer overwrites the previous one.

You have an essential problem here in that you do not know before splitting the string how many pieces there will be.  You could nevertheless get an upper bound on that by counting the number of delimiter characters and adding 1.  You could then allocate space for that many `char` pointers plus one.  Alternatively, you could build a linked list to handle the pieces as you tokenize, then allocate the result array only after you know how many pieces there are.

As for `str`, if you want to return pointers into it, as apparently you do, then it needs to be dynamically allocated, too.  If your platform provides `strdup()` then you could just use

```
char *str = strdup(s);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to check the length, allocate enough space with `malloc()` (including space for the terminator), and copy the input string into the allocated space, presumably with `strcpy()`.  Normally you would want to free the string afterward, but you must not do that if you are returning pointers into that space.

On the other hand, you might consider returning an array of strings that can be *individually* freed.  For that, you must allocate each substring individually (`strdup()` would again be your friend if you have it), and in that event you would want to free the working space (or allow it to be cleaned up automatically if you use a VLA).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do -

```
char str[strlen(s)];  //size should be equal to strlen(s)+1
```

Extra `1` for `'\0'`.  Right now you pass `str` (not terminated with `'\0'`) to `strtok` which causes *undefined behaviour* .

And second thing ,you also need allocate memory to each pointer of `nystring` and then use `strcpy` instead of pointing to `temp`(*don't forget space for nul terminator*).